# Detect duplicate definitions of a variable in shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, symbols

It appears GCC linker doesn't care for one variable being defined in two files. I suspect this is the cause of trouble a 3rd party library is causing us.

Take this:

File a.cpp contains:

```
 int foo;
 //do things with it.
```

File b.cpp contains:

```
 int foo;
 //do other things with it.
```

File c.cpp contains:

```
 extern int foo;
 //do other things with it.
```

They are all compiled by gcc to .o files, then linked as shared object.

```
 gcc -fPIC -c a.cpp
 gcc -fPIC -c b.cpp
 gcc -fPIC -c c.cpp
 ld *.o -shared  -soname,mylib -o mylib
```

The linker doesn't complain at all, but the resulting binary misbehaves. We suspect there are at least a few conflicts of this kind and would like to locate them. What kind of linker options would let us detect them?

(interestingly, if the variables are initialized (`int foo=0`) in both files, it produces an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems compiler option `-fno-common` forces all the variables to be initialized, so it triggers errors upon linking.

Answer (score 1):

Hold on now -- are you using foo for two different purposes in the two files? That would certainly lead to run-time errors. If foo needs to be global, then it should be defined in just one module -- the linker may accept it, but you will still only get one copy of foo. If it doesn't need to be global, it should be declared 'static int foo;'

Comment: I agree, often yes. Sometimes understanding the motivations of original authors gives me a headache. Sometimes it should be that one is static, sometimes one should be extern, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a serious design bug in gcc/ld, it does not occur using MSVC. It won't happen linking programs, only shared libraries. When you link a program, the linker ensures all external references are satisfied, at least at link time. When you link a shared library it does not. Instead, external references for which there are no definitions are just left to dangle, the argument (given in ld man page) being that the symbol has to be resolved at load-time dynamically anyhow, so there's no point checking it. It's also hard if you use the stupid feature of shared libraries grabbing symbols from executables.

Your program will not misbehave. If you specify that symbols in a library must be satisfied on loading, you will get a load-time error, if you specify lazy linkage, the error will still occur, but only on the first use of the symbol (AFAIK!)

Some older OS, I believe BSD for example, allowed unsatisfied external pointers to be left as NULL so that you could write an "in program" check to see if the symbol was linked or not. Linux ld at least does not support this AFAIK.

There is a linker switch to force satisfaction of external references for shared libraries, but it is hard to use correctly in portable builds because it requires you to explicitly link the startup library for your processor.

I consider this a very serious design bug, and tried to file a bug report. In my own product we were happy to be able to build under Cygwin because underneath it uses MSVC linker which does not permit this behaviour, quite a lot of bugs were found in my code this way.

Comment: Actually, what you're writing about is a different problem we had too (but we got the compiler somehow to at least warn of those.) You mean a situation like when there's an `extern int x;` with no `int x;` ever, so if it's referenced at runtime, the definition is not found. This is different: there's  `extern int x;` and more than one `int x;`.